# Eyed3 write ID3 YEAR tag to Mp3

Tags: python-3.x

Using eyed3 I have no problems setting all other tags than the YEAR tag, also there is no problem reading the .getBestDate() put I can't write the tag.

```
import eyed3
audiofile = eyed3.load("Example.mp3")

print(audiofile.tag.getBestDate()) # returns the Year

audiofile.initTag()
audiofile.tag.xxxxxxxxx = ("1843") # how to write the Year?
audiofile.tag.save()
```

I have trawled the manual https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/eyed3/latest/eyed3.pdf and google but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The year tag is simply `year` :

```
audiofile.tag.year
```

But I've never been able to get it to successfully add the year, never see any errors, it's just always blank.

Comment: to set the tag you have to use fields like recording_date, you also need to it's date class : from eyed3.core import Date
af.tag.recording_date = Date(2020)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this today and it successfully shows up in various music programs as having updated the "year" field.

```
import eyed3
from eyed3.core import Date

...

audiofile = eyed3.load("Example.mp3")
audiofile.initTag()
audiofile.tag.recording_date = Date(1976)  # numeric 
audiofile.tag.save()
```